# Gramm Schmidt QR factorisation doesn't return Q and R correctly

Tags: matlab, octave, matrix-inverse

I have implemented a MATLAB function for Gramm-Schmidt QR factorisation. Q's inverse should be equal to it's inverse, but it's not, and I can't see why. I even tried with somebody else's function, which is identical, and the result was the same. This is my function:

```
function [Q R] = gramschmidt(A)
    [n n] = size(A);

    for i = 1:n
        R(i,i) = norm( A(:, i) );
        Q(:, i) = A(:, i) / R ( i, i);

        for j = i + 1 : n
            R(i, j) = Q(:, i)' * A(:, j);
            A(:, j) = A(:, j) - Q(:, i) * R(i, j);
        end
    end
end
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think what you meant to say is Q's *conjugate transpose* should be equal to it's inverse, i.e. that it is a *unitary* matrix.

Secondly, what makes you think that Q returned by your function is not unitary? Let's check.

```
A = randn(20,20);
[Q, R] = gramschmidt(A);

diff = @(X,Y) max(abs(X(:)-Y(:)));  % element-wise max abs difference
diff(Q'*Q, eye(size(A)))
ans =
   1.7764e-15
```

As you can see, it is unitary to a very good precision.

Also, just in case, Matlab has a built-in and efficient `qr` function that performs this decomposition, which also handles rectangular matrices, not just square ones like your implementation.

Comment: I see now, I was lacking information. You are right, I was expecting the wrong result, I thought Q's transpose should be equal to its inverse, as in Householder. Meanwhile, I saw the difference and I sorted it out, thank you!